# Shell Scripting using array

Tags: bash, sh

How I can save multiple file name with absolute path in one file with runtime path provided by the user using shell scripting? Can we do it using array?

Answer (score 0):

Are the files presently in an array? Like so:

```
$export file_arr=("file1" "file2")
```

and in your program:

```
outfile=out.txt

for item in "${file_arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$item" >> "$outfile"
done
```

Comment: @Jahid Sure it will, unless you are referring to the unquoted `$item` that I just fixed.

Comment: @chepner I am not referring to that. You need the filenames to be null terminated, otherwise you won't be able to use it from that file if filename contains newline. filename with newline will just break into a new line in the file and make the part of the filename as a complete path which isn't true.

Comment: Ah; you can use `printf '%q\n' "$item"` in that case, although reading the name back *in* will be a bit tricky. (I can't think of a way that doesn't involve `eval`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
> input.txt
while true
do
    echo "Do you want to continue?"
    read choice
    case "$choice" in
      n|N) break;;
      y|Y) echo "Give The Absolute Path To Be Copied"
        read char
        echo $char >> input.txt
        ;;
      *) echo 'Response not valid';;
    esac
done
```